# How to change required field asterisk color in WooCommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I would like to change the asterisk `*` required field's color in the woocommerce forms because it is generating a problem with the WAVE accessibility scan.

Is there a CSS code to use? Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change asterisk `*` required field's color with `css`. Use the following selector to target it:

```css
.woocommerce form .form-row .required{
  color: #000 !important; /* Change "#000" to your preferred color */
}
```

Which outputs this:

[image]